# Wicket - refresh component on evry Request (implementing session timeout countdown)

Tags: java, session, timeout, refresh, wicket

i have a Wicket 6.10.0 Web Application. I want to implement a timer display the remaining time in the current user session. Something link this:
http://jsfiddle.net/justinobney/uZMGD/

I have a Wicket `Label` in the footer of my Page. This label uses JavaScript to countdown the time from for example 5 minutes down to 0 min 0 sek. This countdown (label) should be refreshed on every request.

Now the question is how to do this?

In the `init()` method i added and `AbstractRequestCycleListener` which notifies me of every end request like this:

```
  getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {

     @Override
     public void onEndRequest(RequestCycle cycle) {
        super.onEndRequest(cycle);
        System.out.println("End Request - here i would like to refresh somehow the label");

     }

  });
```

but i dont know how to send this message to the Label to refresh itself. Any ideas?

*** E D I T : ***
I have a SPA:

```
<body>
lots of AJAX components here
<div wicket:id="footer">Footer always stays here. <br />
Session timeout in: <span wicket:id="sessionTimeoutLabel">countdown here</span>
</div>
</body>
```

The countdown works a little bit like this: http://jsfiddle.net/justinobney/uZMGD/

Now on every AJAX Request i need the `sessionTimeoutLabel` label to rerender to start counting from lets say 600 seconds down to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Don't focus too much on the "end of request". This is about 10µs after to the render phase. Also note that the session timeout is reset after each request, so there is no need to update the label with a new value, other than to reset it to the session timeout parameter.

You should just have a parameter somewhere that dictates the session timeout you configured, and use that to show the label, if it is application specific you can create a getter in your Application class:

```java
public MyApplication extends WebApplication {
    public static final int SESSION_TIMEOUT = 30; // minutes

    public int getSessionTimeout() {
        return SESSION_TIMEOUT;
    }
}
```

And in your footer you can add a label:

```java
add(new Label("timeout", PropertyModel.of(this, "application.sessionTimeout")));
```

Or if it is a property of your session, you can add the getter to your custom session:

```java
public MySession extends WebSession {
    public static final int SESSION_TIMEOUT = 30; // minutes

    public int getSessionTimeout() {
        return SESSION_TIMEOUT;
    }
}
```

And retrieve it in your label:

```java
add(new Label("timeout", PropertyModel.of(this, "session.sessionTimeout")));
```

The expression for the property models make use of the fact that Component has a [getter for the Application](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getApplication%28%29) and a [getter for the Session](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getSession%28%29).

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I've edited my question. I need to add the sessionTimeoutLabel to an `AjaxRequestTarget` after every request to that it will be rerendered.

Comment: I didn't tested it, but you can overwrite onEvent for the Label component, get the AjaxRequestTarget (RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class)), check if its not null and add the label to it. BTW +1 for Martijn answer.

Comment: I know i can override `onEvent()`, but to which event it should react? `Request` or `RequestCycle` dont implement `IEventSource` ...

Comment: You can ignore the event and retrieve the AjaxRequestTarget using mrak's description. If it is null, it is a normal page refresh, if it is available add the label (the this pointer in the event handler) to the target

Comment: Also my comment still remains: the (HTTP) session timeout will be reset regardless if it is an Ajax request.

Comment: Just little background info why you can "ignore" the event: [Wicket creates new default Event with AjaxRequestTarget as payload on every ajax response](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5#MigrationtoWicket1.5-Defaultajaxevent).

Comment: The Default Ajax Event is what is was looking for. Post it as an answer please - i will accept it.